# Disable add to cart button when product is out of stock

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to disable the 'Add to cart' button when product is out of stock with PHP code or a WooCommerce admin setting.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some plugins which provide the facilities to hide "Add To Cart" buttons from the shop and single product page in woocommerce,

[ https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-add-to-cart-button/) ]

[ https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-add-to-cart-woocommerce/ ]

These plugins will do,

1) Hide Add to Cart button from product single page.
2) Hide Add to Cart button from category page.
3) Hide Add to Cart button from homepage and all other pages.

Also you can hide it via adding the below function in functions.php,

```
 /*
 * Override via functions.php
 **/
 if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
 function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
    woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding the function, it would be better to handle `woocommerce_is_purchasable` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'vna_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function vna_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    return true || false; // depending on your condition
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question upon helping a friend. Not being a wordpress developer myself, let alone woocommerce, I still managed to have something to work without writing any PHP, only with CSS.

It seems WooCommerce does a good job "transforming" many product properties in CSS classes that are then assigned to HTML containers. I'm not sure if it's related to the theme, but in my case I ended up with some container having the class "instock" when product was in stock, and "outofstock" when product was...out of stock.

When I noticed that, it didn't take me long to come with some CSS rules to:

1. Hide the button
2. Show a message instead, using CSS pseudo-element and content
3. Make some part of the product tile semi-transparent so that they look more "inactive"

I wouldn't advise it for production code for a big company, but in my case that did the job good enough. Oh and it works fine with products having variations, they get the "outofstock" class only when all variations are out of stock

I won't post any code cause as I said I'm no expert so I can not tell whether my HTML is "generic woocommerce" or linked with the theme used or even completely custom (I'm not the one creating and managing the site usually), but still I think it can help as it helped me big time.

Answer (score 0):

To remove add to cart button from specific product page you can add this code in functions.php (located in the theme folder):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpblog_specific_product');
function wpblog_specific_product($purchaseable_product_wpblog, $product) {
return ($product->id == specific_product_id (512) ? false :     $purchaseable_product_wpblog);
}
```

Reference: https://www.wpblog.com/add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the following snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', function() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
};
```